# Calling a .hide function within a function

Tags: jquery, function, simplecart

I'm using simplecart.js to handle e-commerce on my site.

I have the following script. Essentially this calculates my postage prices, it starts with a base value of £2 and adds values based on the number of products in the basket. Works great.

Problem is that because it uses a base price of £2, this shows up even if there is nothing in the basket. So I'd like to 'hide' the div that contains the postage price if the basket quantity is 0, or the basket is empty. The logic is: less than 9 products, start with 2 + the quantity in the basket. Anything above 9 return a value of £12.

I attempted to use the .hide but am now aware this won't work as it's calling a function within a function, and it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas how I could implement this?

```
<script>
simpleCart({
shippingCustom: function(){
  if (simpleCart.quantity() == 0){
          $('.postage').hide();
        } else if (simpleCart.quantity() < 9 {
    return (2 + simpleCart.quantity());
  } else {
          return 12;
        }
}
</script>
```

Script can be found at the bottom of [this page](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/gracie.html). You can open the basket to see what I mean about the default £2 value.

Comment: Are you sure simpleCart.quantity() return 0? Your code should work.

Comment: Yep, the empty function I have removes everything from the cart to make the value 0.

Comment: function call within a function will of course work, only problem with your code i see is a missing parenthesis in `else if`, is that a typo?

Comment: Could you point out the missing parenthesis? It's probably that!

Comment: else if (simpleCart.quantity() < 9 ) {

Comment: `else if (simpleCart.quantity() < 9 ) {`

Comment: Good spot, however this doesn't fix the problem. There is something wrong in the logic. It no longer calculates any postage price (always stuck at 0 now) and it doesn't hide it either (essentially NONE of the code above is now working.)

Comment: also `});` missing from end of script, i.e `});</script>`

Comment: Hi I spotted that but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the opposite logic.  Set the cart on default to be hidden (either in css or through a js script). Then you show the cart when it has the desired value:

```
if (simpleCart.quantity() > 0){
  $('.postage').show(); 
}
```

You may need to use a .change() or .click() function though (depending on how you have it setup), so that the `$('.postage').show();` will trigger based on the user clicking the 'Add to Cart' button.

Comment: Thanks. Would you implement this as a separate script? I.e I should strip out all the code about the 0 values from my code above (as it used to be, it was just if < 9 do this, else 12) and then write this in to handle the showing and hiding separately from the calculations?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a separate script, but making it a separate function would be good in terms of clean code.